# :any option for rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 2 you can use the :any option to define a custom route that responds to any request method e.g.

```
map.resources :items, :member => {:erase => :any}
```

rails 3 doesn't seem to support the :any option

```
resources :items do
  get :erase, :on => :member # works
  any :erase, :on => :member # doesn't work
end
```

does anyone know if this option has been removed or just renamed?

Answer (score 12):

From digging around and seeing what the `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete` actions actually do in `ActionDispatch`, I *think* all you need to do is `match`. So:

```
resources :items do
  get :erase, :on => :member
  match :erase, :on => :member
end
```

I don't think that syntax for match is actually documented, but the routes it constructs are, atleast for me, what you'd expect from an `all` method

Comment: Additionally, you can (ostensibly) specify methods with the :via specification (:via => [ :any, :get, :put, :post, :delete ]); so far as I can tell, :any does not work (oddly nil seems to, although the routing table will then show a blank instead of ANY), but leaving out :via equates to :any.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Looking at the [Edge Rails routing guide](http://guides.rails.info/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) and the [Rails 3 source](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L237) it doesn't look like it's supported. You could raise a ticket in the [Rails Lighthouse](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/) (I couldn't find an existing one for this).

Answer (score 0):

Match will work, but not inside a resources definition unfortunately.  I rather wish they'd bring back a way to define get/post at least together..

Comment: Hmm? It worked just fine for me inside the resources block. Using Rails 3.0.0.beta4

Comment: Aah - my problem was :on => :member.  I was using my resource name (:on => :item).

The error message isn't very good apparently..

"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:738:in `match': can't define route directly in resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)"